# How could constant array in C changed

Tags: c

I created a const array `string` with 7 elements and a sentinel character at the end of array. But when I use `scanf("%s", string)` and enter a new string with more than 7 elements, such as "`10987654321`", this constant array is modified. How could that happen? I mean, this is the constant array; how could it be changed, and receive more than 7 elements that I declared in the head of my code? Can anybody explain for me?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    const char string[8] = "1234567";

    printf("string initialize is: %s", string);
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("scanfing d\n");
    scanf("%s", string);
    printf("string now: %s\n", string); 
    return 0;
}
```

My output is:

```
string initialize is: 1234567
scanfing d
10987654321
string now: 10987654321
```

Comment: Could you post the output you get, please

Comment: thank Mike, I added the output, sorry for my carelessness

Comment: `string[8]`, where do `4321` get stored in `10987654321`? (reserving room for the *nul-terminating* character)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yes, it's exactly what I don't understand

Comment: Well, the only thing to understand is you have written more characters to your `string` array then you allocated. When that occurs (it is called writing beyond the bounds of the array), you invoke *Undefined Behavior*, meaning the defined operation of your code is no longer guaranteed. Since you have written to memory you do not own, you can overwrite other values on the stack, you can SegFault, the program can appear to work correctly, or anything in between. (anything can happen, the behavior is undefined). The reliable operation ceased when undefined behavior was invoked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is undefined behavior because you should always treat variables declared with `const` as immutable (non-modifiable).

Specific implementations may allow certain const variables to be changed, but in the code you've shown it's still UB and you should always avoid such code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understood this is an Undefined Behavior but I still don't understand where is the rest of entered array is stored?

Comment: @dan9duong7 Because your "string" is placed on stack, and your platform doesn't enforce "read only" on such variables, it's possible to change that variable. If you declare "string" as a static variable, then it's placed on heap where there's very likely proper access control and you wouldn't be able to change it.

Answer (score 1):

It is undefined behavior. The format specifier `%s` is for `char*` but you pass a `const char*` (the array decays).

Undefined behavior means that the standard doesn't define any behavior for your program. It could print what you see, it could print the original string, it could print gibberish, it could crash or anything could happen.

Also please enable compiler warnings. This would have been caught:

> warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type
>   'const char *' [-Wformat]
>
> ```
> scanf("%s", string);
>
>        ~~   ^~~~~~
>
>        %7s
> ```

Regarding writing more than you allocated. Considering the array was not const (mutable) then writing more that 7 characters to it would also be Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't know how to enable compiler warnings, I'm using Dev C++ with default setting, and it does not show any warning at all. It just runs the exe file after compiled. As you said, it's a Undefined Behavior, but I still don't understand where is the rest of entered array is stored?

Answer (score 1):

In a follow on to your comment and the difficulty you are having understand why you can write to the `const` qualified array in your `scanf` call, declaring the character array `string` as `const` protects you the programmer from changing the contents of `string` by issuing a compiler warning (provided by the `-Wformat` option). It does not make the array `string` itself immutable. It will issue a notice (a warning) if you try and change the contents -- that you are attempting to write into a constant object. It does not change the storage itself to *read-only* nor change the data segment within which `string` is stored to `.rodata`.

If you then discard the warning and ignore what the compiler is telling you, then depending on the compiler you may very well succeed in changing the contents of `string`, but you invoke *Undefined Behavior* doing so. See [C11 Standard - 6.7.3 Type qualifiers(p6)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.3p6). Further, undefined behavior results again when you write beyond the bounds of your array.

For example, take your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    const char string[8] = "1234567";

    printf ("string initialize is: %s, string\n\nscanfing d\n", string);
    scanf ("%s", string);
    printf ("string now: %s\n", string); 

    return 0;
}
```

When you attempt to compile this program with warnings properly enabled, e.g.

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -o /tmp/bin/conststring conststring.c
```

the compiler will issue a warning similar to:

```
conststring.c: In function ‘main’:
conststring.c:8:5: warning: writing into constant object (argument 2) [-Wformat=]
     scanf ("%s", string);
 ^
```

That spells it out "**warning: writing into constant object**". Don't do that.

(**note:** older versions of the VS compiler will not flag the warning even if full warnings are enable with `/Wall`)

Further, assuming there were no `const` qualifier, you would want to protect your array bounds by including a *field-width* modifier to the `"%s"` format-specifier to limit the number of characters that could be read, e.g.

```
    scanf ("%7s", string);
```

**note:** the field-width modifier cannot be a variable or named constant, it must be an actual numeric value making it one of the only times it is acceptable to use a *magic number* within your code.

So, in short, you have two primary problems (1) you make a promise to the compiler to only treat `string` as constant and then turn around and break the promise; and (2) you write beyond the bounds of your array. Both invoke *Undefined Behavior*.

Answer (score -1):

1. `string` is allocated on the stack since it is `const char[]` instead of `const char *`. What happens is a `char` array is allocated on the stack, and the string is copied into that array. If you used the `const char *` form, most compilers will place the string into a read-only section in the binary, causing the program to crash when you actually attempt to write to it. On the stack, there is no such protection.
2. `scanf` uses variadic arguments, meaning the compiler does not know that it will modify the array that you pass in (it might do it anyways, but this is not required by the C standard).

Comment: This would be better in comment than as a answer.